# How do I make my for loop properly calculate means over time?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, debugging, data.table

I have data on all the NCAA basketball games that have occurred since 2003.  I am trying to implement a for loop that will calculate the average of a number of stats for each time at a point in time.  Here is my for loop:

```
library(data.table)

roll_season_team_stats <- NULL

for (i in 0:max(stats_DT$DayNum)) {
  stats <- stats_DT[DayNum < i]
  roll_stats <- dcast(stats_DT, TeamID+Season~.,fun=mean,na.rm=T,value.var = c('FGM', 'FGA', 'FGM3', 'FGA3', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'OR', 'DR', 'TO'))
  roll_stats$DayNum <- i + 1
  roll_season_team_stats <- rbind(roll_season_team_stats, roll_stats)
}
```

Here is the output from dput:

```
structure(list(Season = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), DayNum = c(10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), TeamID = c(1104L, 1272L, 
1266L, 1296L, 1400L, 1458L, 1161L, 1186L, 1194L, 1458L), FGM = c(27L, 
26L, 24L, 18L, 30L, 26L, 23L, 28L, 28L, 32L), FGA = c(58L, 62L, 
58L, 38L, 61L, 57L, 55L, 62L, 58L, 67L), FGM3 = c(3L, 8L, 8L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L), FGA3 = c(14L, 20L, 18L, 9L, 14L, 
12L, 8L, 14L, 11L, 17L), FTM = c(11L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 11L, 23L, 
32L, 15L, 10L, 15L), FTA = c(18L, 19L, 29L, 31L, 13L, 27L, 39L, 
21L, 18L, 19L), OR = c(14L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 17L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
9L, 14L), DR = c(24L, 28L, 26L, 19L, 22L, 24L, 18L, 35L, 22L, 
22L), TO = c(23L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 9L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102004ae0>)
```

The loop runs successfully but it is not producing the correct output.  Rather than showing the team averages over time, it is giving me the same number (what I assume is the overall mean of each stat) for each day.  Any ideas what is wrong with my loop? Thanks!

Comment: You are not using `stats` that you assign in first line of loop. Use `stats` and not `stats_DT` in `dcast`.

Comment: If I change stats_DT to stats I get the following error:

Comment: Error in dcast.data.table(stats, TeamID + Season ~ ., fun = mean, na.rm = T,  : 
  Can not cast an empty data.table

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to compute the *cumulative mean* of some variables for each team and season "*showing the team averages over time*".

Although the OP uses the term "*roll*", e.g., `roll_stats` or `roll_season_team_stats`, his code suggests that he is not after a rolling mean but wants to compute cumulative means from the first `DayNum` on, e.g.:

```
stats <- stats_DT[DayNum < i]
```

However, cumulative means can be calculated directly without creating the result piecewise in a `for` loop or by `lapply()` and combining the pieces afterwards.

Unfortunately, the sample dataset provided by the OP does contain rows for many different teams but no *history*, i.e., no data for the same team for a number of consecutive days. Therefore, I have modified the sample dataset for demonstration:

```
# create new sample data set
stats_DT2 <- copy(stats_DT)[, TeamID := c(1:2, 1:4, 1:4)][]
stats_DT2
```

> ```
>     Season DayNum TeamID FGM FGA FGM3 FGA3 FTM FTA OR DR TO
>  1:   2003     10      1  27  58    3   14  11  18 14 24 23
>  2:   2003     10      2  26  62    8   20  10  19 15 28 13
>  3:   2003     11      1  24  58    8   18  17  29 17 26 10
>  4:   2003     11      2  18  38    3    9  17  31  6 19 12
>  5:   2003     11      3  30  61    6   14  11  13 17 22 14
>  6:   2003     11      4  26  57    6   12  23  27 12 24  9
>  7:   2003     12      1  23  55    2    8  32  39 13 18 17
>  8:   2003     12      2  28  62    4   14  15  21 13 35 19
>  9:   2003     12      3  28  58    5   11  10  18  9 22 17
> 10:   2003     12      4  32  67    5   17  15  19 14 22  6
> ```

Now, as there are 2 to 3 rows for each team, the cumulative means can be calculated by:

```
# define function for cummulative mean
cummean <- function(x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)
# define variables to compute on
cols <- c('FGM', 'FGA', 'FGM3', 'FGA3', 'FTM', 'FTA', 'OR', 'DR', 'TO')
# compute aggregates 
stats_DT2[order(DayNum), c(.(DayNum = DayNum), lapply(.SD, cummean)), 
          .SDcols = cols, by = .(TeamID, Season)][]
```

> ```
>     TeamID Season DayNum   FGM  FGA  FGM3  FGA3  FTM   FTA    OR    DR    TO
>  1:      1   2003     10 27.00 58.0 3.000 14.00 11.0 18.00 14.00 24.00 23.00
>  2:      1   2003     11 25.50 58.0 5.500 16.00 14.0 23.50 15.50 25.00 16.50
>  3:      1   2003     12 24.67 57.0 4.333 13.33 20.0 28.67 14.67 22.67 16.67
>  4:      2   2003     10 26.00 62.0 8.000 20.00 10.0 19.00 15.00 28.00 13.00
>  5:      2   2003     11 22.00 50.0 5.500 14.50 13.5 25.00 10.50 23.50 12.50
>  6:      2   2003     12 24.00 54.0 5.000 14.33 14.0 23.67 11.33 27.33 14.67
>  7:      3   2003     11 30.00 61.0 6.000 14.00 11.0 13.00 17.00 22.00 14.00
>  8:      3   2003     12 29.00 59.5 5.500 12.50 10.5 15.50 13.00 22.00 15.50
>  9:      4   2003     11 26.00 57.0 6.000 12.00 23.0 27.00 12.00 24.00  9.00
> 10:      4   2003     12 29.00 62.0 5.500 14.50 19.0 23.00 13.00 23.00  7.50
> ```

Alternatively, the cumulative means can be appended:

```
# append cumulative columns
stats_DT2[order(DayNum), paste0("cm_", cols) := lapply(.SD, cummean), 
          .SDcols = cols, by = .(TeamID, Season)][]
```

> ```
>     Season DayNum TeamID FGM FGA FGM3 FGA3 FTM FTA OR DR TO cm_FGM cm_FGA cm_FGM3 cm_FGA3 cm_FTM cm_FTA cm_OR cm_DR cm_TO
>  1:   2003     10      1  27  58    3   14  11  18 14 24 23  27.00   58.0   3.000   14.00   11.0  18.00 14.00 24.00 23.00
>  2:   2003     10      2  26  62    8   20  10  19 15 28 13  26.00   62.0   8.000   20.00   10.0  19.00 15.00 28.00 13.00
>  3:   2003     11      1  24  58    8   18  17  29 17 26 10  25.50   58.0   5.500   16.00   14.0  23.50 15.50 25.00 16.50
>  4:   2003     11      2  18  38    3    9  17  31  6 19 12  22.00   50.0   5.500   14.50   13.5  25.00 10.50 23.50 12.50
>  5:   2003     11      3  30  61    6   14  11  13 17 22 14  30.00   61.0   6.000   14.00   11.0  13.00 17.00 22.00 14.00
>  6:   2003     11      4  26  57    6   12  23  27 12 24  9  26.00   57.0   6.000   12.00   23.0  27.00 12.00 24.00  9.00
>  7:   2003     12      1  23  55    2    8  32  39 13 18 17  24.67   57.0   4.333   13.33   20.0  28.67 14.67 22.67 16.67
>  8:   2003     12      2  28  62    4   14  15  21 13 35 19  24.00   54.0   5.000   14.33   14.0  23.67 11.33 27.33 14.67
>  9:   2003     12      3  28  58    5   11  10  18  9 22 17  29.00   59.5   5.500   12.50   10.5  15.50 13.00 22.00 15.50
> 10:   2003     12      4  32  67    5   17  15  19 14 22  6  29.00   62.0   5.500   14.50   19.0  23.00 13.00 23.00  7.50
> ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid growing objects in a loop which leads to excessive copying in memory. Instead, build a list of data frames to be row binded **once** outside the loop.

```
dt_list <- lapply(0:max(stats_DT$DayNum), function(i)
              tryCatch(
                  dcast(stats_DT[DayNum < i], 
                        TeamID + Season ~ ., fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE,
                        value.var = c('FGM', 'FGA', 'FGM3', 'FGA3', 
                                      'FTM', 'FTA', 'OR', 'DR', 'TO')
                       )[, DayNum := i + 1],
                       error = function(e) NULL)
           )        

roll_season_team_stats <- data.table::rbindlist(dt_list)
```

In fact, you may be able to do this in base R with `aggregate` on data frames:

```
stats_DF <- data.frame(stats_DT)

df_list <- lapply(0:max(stats_DT$DayNum), function(i)
              tryCatch(
                 transform(aggregate(cbind(FGM, FGA, FGM3, FGA3, 
                                           FTM, FTA, OR, DR) ~ TeamID + Season, 
                                     stats_DF[stats_DF$DayNum < i,],
                                     FUN = mean,
                                     na.rm = TRUE),
                           DayNum = i + 1),
                       error = function(e) NULL)
           )    

roll_season_team_stats <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/ZFWW2984)</kbd>

Comment: First, please delete past comments. See update. You simply needed to wrap loop code in `tryCatch` due to the very first day in each grouping that returns no rows. Online demo for base R solution is included. Also, `data.table` version adjusted for those semantics.